# How to make keyboard work like OSX System Wide?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I switch back and forth between two computers constantly:

- OSX Snow Leopard
- Ubuntu 10.10

I'd like to be able to make Ubuntu use the same keyboard shortcuts as OSX **System Wide**, for the following keyboard sequences only (ie I don't want to make Ctrl act like Super)

- <kbd>Super+C</kbd> -> Copy
- <kbd>Super+V</kbd> -> Paste
- <kbd>Super+T</kbd> -> Open a new tab in whatever browser I'm in.
- <kbd>Super+W</kbd> -> Close a tab in whatever browser I'm in.

**So in short, is there anyway for me to map *just* these keyboard sequences to the following, system wide ?**

- <kbd>Super+C</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
- <kbd>Super+V</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>
- <kbd>Super+T</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>
- <kbd>Super+W</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>

I know there are ways for me to do this for vim, and Firefox, and I'm sure specifically for most applications... but I would prefer to have to do this just once and have it work that way *system wide*!

I'm using a standard PC keyboard, that is "Generic 105 key (intl) PC" on Ubuntu. I'm also using the same keyboard on my Mac mini.

Comment: If you got this dialed in for all the Mac keyboard shortcuts, sharing your config file would be terrific! Thanks

Comment: hey! I wish I still did, but I'm working exclusively on Mac's now, as I've moved jobs ;-) So I don't have my old config around anywhere...

Comment: solutions do not work on elementary OS.'

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you install the `xautomation` package, you can add a command in System → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* → *Custom* like:

```
xte "keyup Meta_L" "keyup Meta_R" "keyup c" "keydown Control_L" "key c" "keyup Control_L"
```

and map that to <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

You may need to use `"keyup Super_L" "keyup Super_R"` depending on your keyboard.

---

Alternative Solution:

Install AutoKey (`apt-get install autokey-gtk`) and set a phrase to:

```
Phrase Text: <ctrl>+C (actually type out the <ctrl>+ here)
Paste Using: Keyboard
Abbreviation: None
Hotkey: <super>+v
Window Filter: None
```

Comment: hey! this looks very promising... i've installed, and can run the above xte command from the terminal, and it outputs "^C" in the terminal... which looks good to me! but when i map it in Keyboard Shortcuts, it doesn't do anything... I tried mapping another program to Meta-C, and it works fine (ie launches fine when I press Meta-C). I also tried specifying the full path to xte (/usr/bin/xte) and that didn't work either... can you try this on your system and see if it works? thanks!

Comment: So xte sends the key codes correctly, but apparently applications see the *combination* of the shortcut and the keypresses sent by xte (e.g. Meta-Control-C).  I've updated my answer to simulate *releasing* the shortcut keys before sending the key presses.

Comment: doesn't work for me even with keyup

Comment: On quick check it works for me, but I've found a solution that will probably be more reliable than xte (even if you get it working).  Check the revised answer.

Comment: hey! thanks @cscarney! your "Alternative Solution" for AutoKey totally works! thanks a ton for your continued effort on this!

Comment: AutoKey works for me, but when I paste using Command/Super+v there's a v in the beginning of the pasted text. For example if I try to copy "this", it will be pasted as "vthis". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Solutions do not work for Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 47):

Since Ubuntu 14 you can use [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks):

```sh
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks # formerly gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then, look for Tweak Tool > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Alt/Win key behavior.

And check: Ctrl is mapped to Win keys and usual Ctrl keys.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does not seem to do anything or is not Mac behavior

Comment: In a fresh install of Ubuntu 16, installing this seems to require gnome-settings-daemon which seems to lead down a trail of packages that don't feel like they were meant to be installed.

Comment: By far the most straight forward option if you just want the command key to be like the cmd key in mac, mainly for copy and paste. I'm on ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: This works great for copy-paste commands and keeps me from constantly opening the search menu thing in Ubuntu.  Now I just need to map Command-Tab to Alt-Tab

Comment: This works for me!

Comment: I can confirm this also works for Ubuntu 18.04. This is the answer you're probably looking for when you came here. Top answer is outdated and doesn't work anymore!

Comment: I don't see Tweak Tool in my apps. What should I do?

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 20.04. You should see application name as `Tweaks` instead of `Tweak Tool`

Comment: This works, but isn't it named backwards? "Win" is mapped to "Ctrl", right? So that pressing "Win" results in "Ctrl" being registered.

Answer (score 17):

There is a way to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Win</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> key:

1. go to **system->preferences->keyboard**,
2. open tab **Layouts**,
3. click **Options...**,
4. open **<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd> key behavior**,
5. and select **Control is mapped to Win keys**

And for console there is a forum post how to do that [here](http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=633403).

For more digging check general Linux keyboard HOWTO [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html).

regards

Comment: hey @danizmax - thanks for the reply... but I'd specifically like to avoid changing the complete behaviour of Ctrl... I find it screws with other things if I do... I'd really like to map just the keyboard shortcuts that I mentioned in the post... thanks though!

Comment: Well the Ctr+ stays as it is. It only duplicates all Ctrl+ to Super+ so you just add the behavior. Unless you really really wanna change only those you mentioned, you'll have to do a lot of digging with xmodmap and loadkeys. I've added the link to the general Linux keyboard HOWTO. Hope it helps :P

Comment: This was the easiest solution from all proposed.

Comment: I don't see the "options" or "alt/win key behavior" option in the system settings any more in Ubuntu 15.10 wily.

Comment: I don't see "layouts" either.

Comment: The answer is 6 years old, the settings window may have changed since then... bear in mind open source applications change often.

Comment: that's now in gnome tweaks, "keyboard and mouse"

Comment: This will not work with 18.04 or later. Check my updated answer  below

Answer (score 16):

Some of the above solutions are old and not working with Ubuntu 18.04. Here is an updated answer

1. Install **gnome-tweaks** if not installed in the system

   `sudo apt-get install  gnome-tweaks`
2. Open the list of applications by pressing **Show Applications** on at the left bottom.
3. Note that this will only change the behavior of WINDOWS key to CMD key and keeps CTRL key as same as before (you will have 2 CTRL keys). If you don't like this, skip step 4 and go to step 5
4. Look for `Tweaks application --> Keyboard and Mouse --> Additional Layout options --> Alt/Win behavior --> Select Control is mapped to Win keys and the usual Ctrl Keys`.
5. Skip this step if you completed step 4. This step will swap Windows key Behaviour to Ctrl and vice versa. Look for `Tweaks application --> Keyboard and Mouse --> Additional Layout options --> Ctrl Position --> Select Swap Left Win with Left Ctrl`
6. One more thing I miss from macOS is the ability to switch windows with CMD+Tab (In this case Windows+Tab). To achieve this go to `Settings --> Keyboard --> Look for Switch Windows under navigation section --> Double Click it and press Windows+Tab when pop up appears`

Comment: Following the same procedure as Step 6, you can look for Launchers > Search in the Keyboard settings, and map that to WINDOWS + SPACE to mimic Spotlight.

Answer (score 11):

Bumping this! **Your pinkies will thank me**

*All* of my muscle memory is Mac based, and I use a Mac at work and in my personal life, but I happened across a *Dell Latitude E7470* and figured I might as well give Linux a go on it (since my Macbook Pro is from 2012 and is pretty heavy, and I just didn't want to have to bother with *\r\n* line endings). So it's been a slow-moving work in progress to figure out how to modify the system to match my muscle memory instead of relearning keyboard shortcuts.

At first, I was just using the Keyboard > Layouts > Options... settings for *"Ctrl is mapped to Alt; Alt is mapped to Win"* but, and this is a very minor thing, I didn't like that my settings didn't apply until *after* I got past the greeter. I was also having trouble getting ~/.Xmodmap to run on start (either by itself, as part of .xinitrc and as a custom startup command in startup applications and in /etc/default/

I'm currently running **Ubuntu MATE 19.10 (Eoan)**, and the keyboard is recognized as a **pc105**

You'll have to modify the script below (or the individual files, if you've already made other modifications to them that you want to keep) to match whatever keyboard your computer has.

Make ~/.Xmodmap:

```
echo '! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
! keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
! keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
! keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
! keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R
! keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
! keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
! keycode 135 = Menu NoSymbol Menu
! keycode 147 = XF86MenuKB NoSymbol XF86MenuKB
! keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
! keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
!
! keycode 105 = Alt_R Meta_R
clear control
clear mod1
clear mod4
keycode 37 = Super_L
keycode 105 = Super_R
keycode 133 = Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 64 = Control_L
keycode 108 = Control_R
add control = Control_L Control_R
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R' > ~/.Xmodmap
```

make ~/.xinitrc:

```
echo 'if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
fi
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap' > ~/.xinitrc
```

Modify X11 Keyboard symbol file for your keyboard (the important part here is the `include "altwin(ctrl_alt_win)"` before `// End of modifier mappings.` This is an otherwise unmodified /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc file):

```
echo 'default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "pc105" {

    key <ESC>  {    [ Escape        ]   };

    // The extra key on many European keyboards:
    key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };

    // The following keys are common to all layouts.
    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,    bar ]   };
    key <SPCE> {    [    space      ]   };

    include "srvr_ctrl(fkey2vt)"
    include "pc(editing)"
    include "keypad(x11)"

    key <BKSP> {    [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };

    key  <TAB> {    [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab    ]   };
    key <RTRN> {    [ Return        ]   };

    key <CAPS> {    [ Caps_Lock     ]   };
    key <NMLK> {    [ Num_Lock      ]   };

    key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
    key <LCTL> {    [ Control_L     ]   };
    key <LWIN> {    [ Super_L       ]   };

    key <RTSH> {    [ Shift_R       ]   };
    key <RCTL> {    [ Control_R     ]   };
    key <RWIN> {    [ Super_R       ]   };
    key <MENU> {    [ Menu          ]   };

    // Beginning of modifier mappings.
    modifier_map Shift  { Shift_L, Shift_R };
    modifier_map Lock   { Caps_Lock };
    modifier_map Control{ Control_L, Control_R };
    modifier_map Mod2   { Num_Lock };
    modifier_map Mod4   { Super_L, Super_R };

    // Fake keys for virtual<->real modifiers mapping:
    key <LVL3> {    [ ISO_Level3_Shift  ]   };
    key <MDSW> {    [ Mode_switch       ]   };
    modifier_map Mod5   { <LVL3>, <MDSW> };

    key <ALT>  {    [ NoSymbol, Alt_L   ]   };
    include "altwin(meta_alt)"

    key <META> {    [ NoSymbol, Meta_L  ]   };
    modifier_map Mod1   { <META> };

    key <SUPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Super_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <SUPR> };

    key <HYPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Hyper_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <HYPR> };
    include "altwin(ctrl_alt_win)"
    // End of modifier mappings.

    key <OUTP> { [ XF86Display ] };
    key <KITG> { [ XF86KbdLightOnOff ] };
    key <KIDN> { [ XF86KbdBrightnessDown ] };
    key <KIUP> { [ XF86KbdBrightnessUp ] };
};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "editing" {
    key <PRSC> {
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Print, Sys_Req ]
    };
    key <SCLK> {    [  Scroll_Lock      ]   };
    key <PAUS> {
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Pause, Break ]
    };
    key  <INS> {    [  Insert       ]   };
    key <HOME> {    [  Home         ]   };
    key <PGUP> {    [  Prior        ]   };
    key <DELE> {    [  Delete       ]   };
    key  <END> {    [  End          ]   };
    key <PGDN> {    [  Next         ]   };

    key   <UP> {    [  Up           ]   };
    key <LEFT> {    [  Left         ]   };
    key <DOWN> {    [  Down         ]   };
    key <RGHT> {    [  Right        ]   };
};' >/usr/share/x11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

And just in case, here's the relevant part of /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin if you need to add it manually:

```
// Ctrl is mapped to the Alt, Alt to the Super, and Win to the Ctrl keys.
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ctrl_alt_win" {
    key <LALT> { [ Control_L, Control_L  ] };
    key <RALT> { type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
                 symbols[Group1] = [ Control_R, Control_R ] };
    key <LWIN> { [ Alt_L, Meta_L ] };
    key <RWIN> { [ Alt_R, Meta_R ] };
    key <LCTL> { [ Super_L ] };
    key <RCTL> { [ Super_R ] };
    modifier_map Control { <RALT>, <LALT> };
    modifier_map Mod1 { <LWIN>, <RWIN> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <LCTL>, <RCTL> };
};
```

Modify /etc/defaults/keyboard:

```
echo '# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:shift_nocancel,ctrl:alt,alt:win,win:ctrl"

BACKSPACE="guess"' >/etc/default/keyboard
```

And finally, here's my GNOME and Marco keybinding dconf dumps:

GNOME:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings]
activate-window-menu=['disabled']
begin-move=['disabled']
close=['<Control>q']
maximize=['<Alt><Super>m']
minimize=['<Control>m']
move-to-corner-ne=['disabled']
move-to-corner-nw=['disabled']
move-to-corner-se=['disabled']
move-to-corner-sw=['disabled']
move-to-side-e=['disabled']
move-to-side-n=['disabled']
move-to-side-s=['disabled']
move-to-side-w=['disabled']
move-to-workspace-1=['<Shift><Super>Home']
move-to-workspace-down=['<Shift><Super>Next']
move-to-workspace-up=['<Shift><Super>Prior']
show-desktop=['<Control>F3']
switch-to-workspace-1=['<Super>Home']
switch-to-workspace-down=['<Super>Next']
switch-to-workspace-up=['<Super>Prior']
switch-windows=['disabled']
switch-windows-backward=['disabled']
toggle-fullscreen=['<Control><Super>f']
toggle-maximized=['<Shift><Control>m']
toggle-shaded=['<Alt><Super>s']
unmaximize=['<Control><Alt>m']
```

Marco:

```
[org/mate/marco/global-keybindings]
cycle-group='<Primary>grave'
cycle-panels='disabled'
cycle-windows='<Alt>grave'
run-command-screenshot='<Primary><Shift>numbersign'
run-command-window-screenshot='<Primary><Shift>dollar'
show-desktop='<Primary>F3'
switch-group='<Alt>Tab'
switch-to-workspace-1='<Primary><Mod4>1'
switch-to-workspace-2='<Primary><Mod4>3'
switch-to-workspace-3='<Primary><Mod4>2'
switch-to-workspace-4='<Primary><Mod4>4'
switch-to-workspace-down='<Mod4>Down'
switch-to-workspace-left='<Mod4>Left'
switch-to-workspace-prev='<Shift><Mod4>Tab'
switch-to-workspace-right='<Mod4>Right'
switch-to-workspace-up='<Mod4>Up'
switch-windows='<Primary>Tab'

[org/mate/marco/window-keybindings]
activate-window-menu='disabled'
begin-move='<Primary><Shift><Mod4>m'
begin-resize='<Primary><Shift><Mod4>r'
close='<Primary>q'
maximize='<Alt><Mod4>m'
maximize-horizontally='<Alt><Mod4>h'
maximize-vertically='<Alt><Mod4>v'
minimize='<Primary>m'
move-to-corner-ne='<Alt><Mod4>2'
move-to-corner-nw='<Alt><Mod4>1'
move-to-corner-se='<Alt><Mod4>4'
move-to-corner-sw='<Alt><Mod4>3'
move-to-side-e='<Alt><Mod4>Left'
move-to-side-n='<Alt><Mod4>Up'
move-to-side-s='<Alt><Mod4>Down'
move-to-side-w='<Alt><Mod4>Right'
move-to-workspace-1='<Primary><Alt><Mod4>1'
move-to-workspace-2='<Primary><Alt><Mod4>2'
move-to-workspace-3='<Primary><Alt><Mod4>3'
move-to-workspace-4='<Primary><Alt><Mod4>4'
move-to-workspace-down='<Primary><Mod4>Down'
move-to-workspace-left='<Primary><Mod4>Left'
move-to-workspace-right='<Primary><Mod4>Right'
move-to-workspace-up='<Primary><Mod4>Up'
tile-to-corner-ne='<Shift><Alt>at'
tile-to-corner-nw='<Shift><Alt>exclam'
tile-to-corner-se='<Shift><Alt>dollar'
tile-to-corner-sw='<Shift><Alt>numbersign'
tile-to-side-e='<Shift><Alt>Right'
tile-to-side-w='<Shift><Alt>Left'
toggle-fullscreen='<Primary><Mod4>f'
toggle-maximized='<Primary><Shift>m'
toggle-shaded='<Alt><Mod4>s'
unmaximize='<Alt><Mod4>r'
```

Answer (score 10):

Edit: The simple approach I describe here has some drawbacks (mentioned below, most noticeably with sticky keys).  So I now recommend checking out [Kinto](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto) which avoids such issues by remapping the keyboard proactively.

---

I wanted a solution that would work in any desktop environment / window manager, so I combined cscarney's suggestion to use xautomation with the [SXHKD](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) (the simple X hotkey daemon).

Here is the basic [`~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc`](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/becf7829f5b984bb74e3e749e2d9c6ab20c9fb8e/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc) config file I produced.

Advanced: My [latest version](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc) is more complete, and can send different keystrokes for different applications, but it requires an external script, and probably has some bindings you don't want.

Here is a snippet:

```
# Reload this config
control + alt + shift + r
  killall -USR1 -u "$USER" sxhkd && echo 'sxhkd config reloaded'

# Cut, copy and paste
alt + x
  xte "keyup x" "keyup Meta_L" "keydown Control_L" "key x" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Meta_L"
alt + c
  xte "keyup c" "keyup Meta_L" "keydown Control_L" "key c" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Meta_L"    
alt + v
  xte "keyup v" "keyup Meta_L" "keydown Control_L" "key v" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Meta_L"

# Open tab, close tab, restore closed tab
alt + t
  xte "keyup t" "keyup Meta_L" "keydown Control_L" "key t" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Meta_L"
alt + w
  xte "keyup w" "keyup Meta_L" "keydown Control_L" "key w" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Meta_L"    
alt + shift + t
  xte "keyup t" "keyup Meta_L" "keydown Control_L" "key t" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Meta_L"

# Move to home/end
alt + Left
  xte "keyup Meta_L" "keyup Left" "key Home" "keydown Meta_L"
alt + Right
  xte "keyup Meta_L" "keyup Right" "key End" "keydown Meta_L"
alt + shift + Left
  xte "keyup Meta_L" "keyup Left" "key Home" "keydown Meta_L"
alt + shift + Right
  xte "keyup Meta_L" "keyup Right" "key End" "keydown Meta_L"

# Move one word
super + Left
  xte "keyup Super_L" "keyup Left" "keydown Control_L" "key Left" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Super_L"
super + Right
  xte "keyup Super_L" "keyup Right" "keydown Control_L" "key Right" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Super_L"
super + shift + Left
  xte "keyup Super_L" "keyup Left" "keydown Control_L" "key Left" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Super_L"
super + shift + Right
  xte "keyup Super_L" "keyup Right" "keydown Control_L" "key Right" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Super_L"
```

Note:

- As you can see, if I keyup the original modifier key before performing the virtual stroke, then I keydown it again afterwards.  This means the user can repeat they key press without having to release and depress the modifier key again.  In other words, after pressing Alt-W, the system sees the Alt key is depressed.

Caveats:

- That can be a problem (especially on slower machines) if you release Alt key while the xte command *is still running*.  You will end up with a "sticky" Alt key, because xte has pressed it down for you!
- Using this approach, the triggers *will not repeat* if the key is held down.  (So you can't move 12 words by holding down Super-Left.)

Comment: I used to use [`bbkeys`](https://github.com/bbidulock/bbkeys) in the past, but sadly it is not being packaged on so many distros these days.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on [cscarney's AutoKey hint](https://askubuntu.com/a/11388/6418), I am developing my [AutoKey](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/autokey-gtk) configuration to achieve all this in Ubuntu (OS X-like `<cmd>+c`, `<cmd>+v`, ... Emacs-style `<ctrl>+f`, `<ctrl>+b`, ...) in my [dotfile repo](https://github.com/metakermit/dotfiles/tree/master/autokey).

I don't use basic phrases (where window filtering is [currently broken](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/issues/detail?id=228)), but Python scripts, to be able to disable AutoKey in apps such as Emacs, Eclipse, Vim, gnome-terminal ... where I don't want to mess up the existing shortcuts.

You can check out the `README` on the bottom for instructions on how to set it up.

Comment: link is broken for the app

Comment: @chifliiiii fixed the links, but note that the linked config in my dotfiles is very likely outdated, cause I haven't been using it in years.

Answer (score 4):

This is an easy task once you know how to do it.

1. Check the keycode of yours key. Run this program at terminal.

   ```
   xev</pre>
   ```

   [image]

   At this example, the terminal shows that the keycode for my <kbd>k</kbd> is "45".
2. Change them as you like creating this file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.Xmodmap</pre>
   ```
3. It's contents should look like this example:

   ```
   keycode 64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L  
   keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
   ```

   (Change the keycode number as needed - look at step "1")

   Ilustration:

   [image]

   **Obs.**: if I want to change my <kbd>k</kbd> I should use "keycode 45" as showed at step "1".
4. Logout and log back in or reboot or run this:

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap</pre>
   ```

   Hope you enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You may like to check out [Kinto](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto), which is a fairly comprehensive solution with a full GitHub repository.

> "A better Linux & Windows keyboard layout for professional mac users"

It avoids some of the problems I had with sxhkd, because it doesn't reinterpret keystrokes, rather it remaps them ahead of time using `xmodmap`.

Specifically, it watches your X session to see when window focus changes, and then it quickly switches to the appropriate keybindings for that application.

Comment: Seems nice but after executing `~/.config/kinto/gui/kinto-gui.py` we are getting errors that the `import gi` is not working properly. Have installed python3 successfully already

Comment: @GeorgePligoropoulos You may want to look at the GitHub issues: https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22import+gi%22

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Kinto is great! it solved all of the problems I was facing because of my muscle memory.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to and based on the excellent work of others, I made a repo with my Autokey shortcuts and instructions for getting this setup:

https://github.com/bliles/autokey-macos

Answer (score 3):

Use kinto:
https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto/

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and it works wonderfully! It uses system wide rebindings so you don't need to deal with configuring individual applications and installation is super simple and takes a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way which I found to remap the keys with mac layout was by installing the app [Kinto](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto).
After the installation, you can use mac os keyboard shortcuts with the command key on Linux/Windows

https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto.git
cd kinto
./setup.py
```

https://youtu.be/kd4al45XD1g

[image]

Comment: This is far and away the easiest solution!  I've used Kinto on several versions of Ubuntu as virtual machines, and now have 20.04 booting from an external drive on an old iMac.  Works perfectly!

Comment: Seems like the easiest solution, I was just wondering how much lightweight this app is

Answer (score 2):

**First**
Install Guest Additions CD (`Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD image`).

**Activate clipboard sharing**
Then after a reboot, in Virtualbox go to `Machine->Settings->General->Advanced` and set
`Shared Clipboard: Bidrectional`

**Change VirtualBox Host Key**
In `Vitualbox/Preferences/Input/Virtual Machine/Host Key Combination`
choose sth different then <kbd>⌘</kbd>

**Key Mapping**:
For the `cmd/ctrl` mapping for me adding the English (Macintosh) keyboard seems to be the most comfortable solution :)

Go to `Ubuntu Settings->Text Entry`
(I guess in older versions it might be in Keyboard Layout Settings)
Under `Input sources to use:` hit plus (+)
add `English (Macintosh)`

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64bit in VirtualBox 5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I have an Apple aluminum keyboard. A slight modification (using Super_L instead of Meta_L) to @cscarney's suggestion made it work in Ubuntu 18.04

```
Command: xte "keyup Super_L" "keyup c" "keydown Control_L" "key c" "keyup Control_L"
Short cut: Super+C

Command: xte "keyup Super_L" "keyup v" "keydown Control_L" "key v" "keyup Control_L"
Short cut: Super+V
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Ubuntu to hand (Mac's here, Ubu's at the office) but I use a Mac keyboard there and for the same reasons as you, wanted to do this.

First thing is to make sure your keyboard was installed as a Mac keyboard. I think you can change this in system->preferences->keyboard. While you're there one of the tabs will get you to a key mapping page where you can set up how the cmd key works.

Like I say, I can't remember exactly - I can point to the bits on my screen here, but that doessn't work because I'm not there.

If you're still stuck tomorrow, I'll look again.

Comment: system->preferences->keyboard->layouts->options

Comment: hi leo... i'm not using a Mac keyboard with Ubuntu though... I'm using a standard PC keyboard, ie "Generic 105 key (intl) PC" did try switching my "keyboard model" to Vendor Apple / Model Apple but that didn't seem to make any difference.... I also tried Vendor Apple / Model Macbook and that didn't seem to change anything either...

Comment: and for what it's worth, I use the exact same PC keyboard on my macmini as well, as I bought it second hand and it didn't come with a mac keyboard. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Autokeys did work for me. Now win+c (v,x,a) work around my system just like I'd expect it.

**1. Install autokeys**

`sudo apt install autokey-gtk`

**2. Configure autokeys**

1. Add root folder, call it something like MacKeys or whatever
2. You'll create 4 scripts in there for ctrl-c, v,x and a
3. assign to each script hotkey super-c, super-v etc
4. fill the scripts with code below (replace letter c for other combos)

`winClass = window.get_active_class()
keys = "<ctrl>+c"
if winClass == "gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal":
        keys = "<ctrl>+<shift>+c";
keyboard.send_keys(keys)`

4a. For CmdZ, CmdA or CmdX work with simpler script like `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+x")`

**3. Add /usr/bin/autokey-gtk to startup applications**

**4. Disable win-A in keyboard settings**

Normally win-a makes switch to overview.

**5. Optional, fully prevent win to switch the overview**

Probably you will want to remove it. Install gnome-tweak-tool, go to keyboard and rebind switching from desktop to overview. That worked for my gnome ubuntu 16.04.