# Remap MacbookPro Alt and Command keys?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard-layout, apple, macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make keyboard work like OSX System Wide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10008/how-to-make-keyboard-work-like-osx-system-wide)

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 on my MacBookPro6.2, and I'd like to remap the following keys:

Right-Alt -> Right-cmd 
Right-command (apple key) -> Right-Alt

how do i do this? thanks for all your help