# How to remap Macbook 5,1 damaged 'Ctrl' key to a Command key?

Tags: keyboard-layout, macbook

I have a macbook and I want to remap the keyboard because my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key stops working so I found this [how to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21183/remap-macbookpro-alt-and-command-keys), but since the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key doesn't work I can't obtend the keycode that this tutorial mention is there another way to do this?.

My MacBook its an Aluminium Unibody (5,1) btw

Comment: Do macs not have 2 control keys? How about you alter the keyboard itself in systemsettings->hardware->keyboards->options->control key position?

Answer (score 1):

You can remap keys with `Xmodmap`.

The code for the <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> button is

```
keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L)
```