# Use cmd key as Super key

Tags: keyboard, mac

Still discovering Ubuntu on my Mac, I would like to know how to change the behaviour of my keyboard and use cmd as the super key (and do stuff like cmd+c for copy).

I'm using a 2010 white Macbook with Ubuntu 16.04.

I have read somewhere that in previous Ubuntu versions there were something to activate in the settings like "Use win command as Super" but correct me if I'm wrong, it's not in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: please post the link to this article.

Comment: @George here it is http://askubuntu.com/a/11058

Comment: That article should be helpful. The issue is you need to know the __scancode__ for your _mac_ computer then map that in __system settings-->keyboard__ 0n Ubuntu to any behaviour you want. That articel has several links which I think you should look at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a *mac* but saw this articles that should help:

1. From an *[askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10008/how-to-make-keyboard-work-like-osx-system-wide/11058#11058)*:

   - use of the *xautomation package*, or
   - use of the *autokey-gtk* package.

Please see if it flies for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this on my Macbook pro, simply run this command in terminal:

```
setxkbmap -option 'altwin:swap_alt_win'
```

You may also want to run this script on start up so you don't have to memorize the command and run it manually on every reboot. You can add this script to your to your startup tasks by running:

```
crontab -e
```

then add a line to execute the script:

```
@reboot path/to/script
```

Enjoy mate