# Different mappings for internal and external keyboard (Windows vs Apple style)

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, apple

I am currently struggling with the following issue:

At work I use an Apple MacBook Pro, whereas personally I use a Dell XPS 13 running Kubuntu. I never had an issue switching between the Apple and Standard (Windows style?) layouts. Recently however I started to use an Apple Magic Keyboard 2 in my home office setup. I use this setup with both laptops, and I realise more and more that I have an issue using Kubuntu with the Magic Keyboard. It just doesn't feel natural to press Ctrl+C for copying for example, even though it's not an issue on the internal keyboard. So what I want to do is use my personal Laptop with different keyboard layouts and shortcuts depending on the keyboard I use.

A few examples to show what I mean:

- use Cmd+C, Cmd+V etc when using the Magic Keyboard, but Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V when using the internal one
- use Cmd+Space to open KRunner with the Magic Keyboard, but use Alt+Space when using the internal one (I use KRunner to search and open software, which is similar to Apple Spotlight in that regard, which is also opened with Cmd+Space)
- Use Cmd+LeftArrow for jumping to the beginning of the line with the Magic keyboard, but use the Pos1 key for this on my internal one

I did find [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard) and also a few questions here on askubuntu, but nothing I found quite fits my requirements.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: It might be possible to have something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/10008/how-to-make-keyboard-work-like-osx-system-wide set and unset when an external keyboard is connected, but I dunno if it's possible to distinguish between identical key presses from two keyboards. Do you want to use both in the same session?

Comment: No that's a good point. Manually switching between the settings should be fine. How would I go about switching back and forth?

Comment: If you go via the autokey methods, it's possible to add a shortcut to enable/disable autokey: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/FAQ#can-i-temporarily-suspendresume-autokey (and if using other X-based methods, maybe use udev: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268171/70524)